# blazor component on a .cshtml page that has a submit button

Tags: .net-core, blazor

Is it possible for a server side blazor component to have  a button allowing the user to change data in the component and have the component in a .cshtml page that has a submit button?
I'm having an issue with postback to the server refreshing the component everytime because the .cshtml is reloaded.  Its like the SignalR hub is not just sending changes to the component.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the blazor component to the razor page, make sure it is not under the same  tag.  The blazor component button has to outside of the form on the .cshtml page.